# Upload on iframe in modal

Tags: php, jquery, forms, symfony, upload

I have a modal containing a form and an iframe.
The form has a file field and post to the iframe.

The php controller return the uniqid (basically the name) of the uploaded file.
The upload works well and my iframe contains the uniqid.

I would like to display this uniqid on my main page.

My issue is that I don't know how to wait the end of the upload to show the uniqid.

**The form and iframe :**

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ path('lesson_upload') }}" target="uploadFrame" method="post">
    <label for="uploadFile">Document :</label>
    <input id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" type="file" />
    <br /><br />
    <input class="btn btn-primary" id="uploadSubmit" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
<div id="uploadInfos">
    <div id="uploadStatus">Aucun upload en cours</div>
    <iframe hidden id="uploadFrame" name="uploadFrame"></iframe>
</div>
```

**The JavaScript to fill the modal with the form :**

```
$(document).on('click', '#computer-upload', function ()
    {
        var url = Routing.generate('lesson_upload_computer');
        $.get(url, function (data)
        {
            $('#modal-various .modal-body').html(data);
            return false;
        });
        return false;
    });
```

**The iframe at the end of an upload :**

```
<div id="uploadInfos">
    <div id="uploadStatus">Aucun upload en cours</div>
    <iframe hidden="" id="uploadFrame" name="uploadFrame">
    #document
        <html>
            <body>
                <body>533ebac647b7e</body>
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use an AJAX upload, after a little research, you cannot add an event that detects when the upload has finished.

You now have 2 options:

**Fetch the id from the iframe** every ~100ms and if it is not empty or null, the id will be in:

```
document.checkForId = function() {
    id = $('#uploadFrame').contents().find('#idInIframeDivOrOtherContainer');
    if (id) {
        window.clearInterval(intervalId);
    }

};
$(document).ready(function() {
    intervalId = window.setInterval('document.checkForId', 100);
});
```

When posting data, **return javascript that sets the id in the main page** (if you have jquery in the iframe):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#divInParentWindow', parent.document).text('<?php echo $id; ?>');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I would suggest making the `checkForId` in to a self calling function that is just kicked off by the `$(document).ready()` as that way you would be able to stop the check once the id is made available, otherwise it would keep going until the page is left. For example... `var $id = $('#uploadFrame').... if (!$id.length) { checkForId(); }`

Answer (score 0):

If your iFrame has its source on the same server/domain level as your main page. You could simply define a function at your main page

```
function iframeHasLoaded() {
  var body = document.getElementById('uploadFrame').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
}
```

And, from your iFrame

```
window.onload=function() { parent.iframeHasLoaded() };
```

This should work.